# User input confirmation

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

After trying to go more generalised approach to WPF (something along MVVM way), I've ran into a problem.

Lets say I have classical Person Class with three string properties - FirstName, LastName, Fullname. First two are entered by user via two TextBoxes, and FullName is readonly and is printed in TextBlock.

I have a stackpanel with two textboxes. I bind Person instance to stackpanel's DataContext. It looks something like this:

```
<StackPanel x:Name="InputData" DataContext="{Binding Person}">
                    <Text="{Binding FirstName, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
                    <Text="{Binding LastName, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
                </StackPanel>
<TextBlock Text="{Binding FullName}"/>
```

And in c#:

```
public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    Person PP= new Person ();

    InputData.DataContext = PP;
}

public class Person : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    string _firstName = "Bob";
    string _lastName = "Smith";

    public string FirstName
    {
        get { return _firstName; }
        set
        {
            _firstName = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("FullName");
        }
    }

    public string LastName
    {
        get { return _lastName; }
        set
        {
            _lastName = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("FullName");
        }
    }

    public string FullName
    {
        get { return string.Format("{0} {1}", FirstName, LastName); }
    }


    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    private void OnPropertyChanged(string property)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(property));
    }
}
```

Now I want to avoid accidental changes to pp. Previously I managed with events and MessageBoxes - after StackPanel lost focus or user pressed Enter a messagebox appeared and asked whever to change pp or not.

If user selected "No" then everything would've returned to its original state before editing.

Otherwise pp and all textboxes would save new values.

Now after trying binding and MVVM I wouldn't really like to go back to all these events, so whats the correct way to do it?

Comment: This question will probably get flagged because it's too broad and largely subjective. The simple answer is "windows dialog boxes are very old-school, don't use them in an MVVM app". If you decide to anyway then there are various ways of doing so, each with their own pros and cons. If you want a hard-core MVVM purist approach then check out [the article I wrote on this topic](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/820324/Implementing-Dialog-Boxes-in-MVVM) along with my sample code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an extremely basic and verbose example of how to do what you're looking for.  The components to make this happen can and should be broken into further processing groups but you'll get the idea with this.

I am going to include 3 classes in the here, the ViewModel, PreviousState, and a RelayCommand.  Then I am going to use pure binding in the View.  Run this code, as is, and it will work the way you want it via pure MVVM.  However; take the time to decipher through what's going on because there are even more in depth yet simpler ways to achieve this result.  I believe this is a well educated example using pure MVVM to help you understand how this can be achieved.  Note: There are a few popular techniques used and in order to help you understand more it would require a short course on MVVM and XAML.  My hopes is that you can pick this apart enough to understand it more and modify it to fit your needs.

I put all the files in the same namespace and he ViewModel, RelayCommand, and PreviousState types all in a single file just to simplify posting this answer.

```
using System;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;
using System.Windows.Input;

namespace Question_Answer_WPF_App
{
    public class PersonViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        string firstName = "Bob";
        string lastName = "Smith";
        string fullName;

        public PersonViewModel()
        {
            CommitStateCommand = new RelayCommand((obj) => CommitChanges(),(obj) => CanExecuteCommands());
            RevertStateCommand = new RelayCommand((obj) => RevertChanges(),(obj) => CanExecuteCommands());
            CommitChanges();
        }

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
        private void Notify([CallerMemberName] string property = "") => PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(property));

        public string FirstName
        {
            get => firstName;
            set
            {
                firstName = value;
                Notify();
                UpdateChanges();
            }
        }

        public string LastName
        {
            get => lastName;
            set
            {
                lastName = value;
                Notify();
                UpdateChanges();
            }
        }

        public string FullName
        {
            get => fullName;
            private set
            {
                fullName = value;
                Notify();
            }
        }

        private PersonState PreviousState { get; } = new PersonState();
        public RelayCommand CommitStateCommand { get; }
        public RelayCommand RevertStateCommand { get; }

        private void UpdateChanges()
        {
            FullName = $"{FirstName} {LastName}";
            CommitStateCommand.UpdateCanExecute();
            RevertStateCommand.UpdateCanExecute();
        }

        private void CommitChanges()
        {
            PreviousState.FirstName = FirstName;
            PreviousState.LastName = LastName;
            UpdateChanges();
        }

        private void RevertChanges()
        {
            FirstName = PreviousState?.FirstName;
            LastName = PreviousState?.LastName;
            CommitChanges();
        }

        private bool CanExecuteCommands() => PreviousState?.FirstName != FirstName || PreviousState?.LastName != LastName;
    }

    internal class PersonState
    {
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        public string LastName { get; set; }
    }

    public class RelayCommand : ICommand
    {
        public Action<object> ExecuteFunction { get; }
        public Predicate<object> CanExecutePredicate { get; }
        public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged;
        public void UpdateCanExecute() => CanExecuteChanged?.Invoke(this, EventArgs.Empty);

        public RelayCommand(Action<object> executeFunction) : this(executeFunction, (obj) => true) { }
        public RelayCommand(Action<object> executeFunction, Predicate<object> canExecutePredicate)
        {
            ExecuteFunction = executeFunction;
            CanExecutePredicate = canExecutePredicate;
        }

        public bool CanExecute(object parameter) => CanExecutePredicate?.Invoke(parameter) ?? true;
        public void Execute(object parameter) => ExecuteFunction.Invoke(parameter);
    }
}
```

**MainWindow.xaml**

```
<Window x:Class="Question_Answer_WPF_App.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Question_Answer_WPF_App"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow"
        Height="450"
        Width="800">

    <Window.DataContext>
        <local:PersonViewModel />
    </Window.DataContext>

    <Window.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="Button">
            <Setter Property="Width" Value="150" />
            <Setter Property="Margin" Value="4" />
        </Style>
    </Window.Resources>

    <StackPanel>
        <TextBlock Text="First Name"/>
        <TextBox Text="{Binding FirstName, Mode=TwoWay}"/>

        <TextBlock Text="Last Name"/>
        <TextBox Text="{Binding LastName, Mode=TwoWay}"/>

        <TextBlock Text="Full Name"/>
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding FullName}" />

        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
            <Button Content="Commit" 
                    Command="{Binding CommitStateCommand}" />
            <Button Content="Revert" 
                    Command="{Binding RevertStateCommand}" />
        </StackPanel>    
    </StackPanel>

</Window>
```

**App Start (cannot commit or revert)**
[image]

**First Name Changed (can commit or revert)**
[image]

**Last Name Changed (can still commit or revert)**
[image]

**Committing Stores New Changes (cannot commit or revert anymore)**
[image]

**Reverting Reverts Changes (cannot commit or revert anymore)**
[image]

Answer (score 0):

There are various ways to accomplish this.
Your previous approach with events was (probably ?) not too bad.

I'd simply create a class in the MVVM library of your program/product, containing events and methods to subscribe from your UI library.

Here's an example to demonstrate this.

MVVM:

```
public delegate void ExceptionEvent(Exception e);

public static class MessageHelper
{
    #region Public API

    public static void OnException(Exception e)
    {
        Exception?.Invoke(e);
    }

    #endregion

    #region Events

    public static event ExceptionEvent Exception;

    #endregion
}
```

UI:

```
static class MessageResolver
{
    #region Constructor

    static MessageResolver()
    {
        MessageHelper.Exception += OnException;
    }

    #endregion

    #region Events

    static void OnException(Exception e)
    {
        new ExceptionDialog(e).ShowDialog();
    }

    #endregion
}
```

Where you simply open a dialog in your UI helper class. You can change it to `EventArgs` [...] but you get the idea.

Basically you instruct a helper to do something.
The UI level is responsible for executing the correct action (e.g. show a dialog or window).